# How do I get ggplot to read the colors I am feeding it

Tags: r

My data basically looks like this:

```
Populations alpha   SE  Z   sample  color
Pop1    0.02    0.003   7   9   red
Pop2    0.03    0.003   10  9   red
Pop3    0.02    0.003   11  8   blue
Pop4    0.03    0.003   14  10  green
```

and I and am plotting as point estimates with error bars. I am having difficulty getting ggplot2 to read my colors.

```
read.table("table.txt", header = TRUE) -> tbl 
require(ggplot2)
tbl$Populations2 <- factor(tbl$Populations, as.character(tbl$Populations))

#pdf(file="table.pdf", width=11)

ggplot(tbl, aes(y = Populations2, x = alpha, xmin = alpha - 
    SE, xmax = alpha + SE, label = Populations2, colour = 
    color)) + geom_point(colour = "black") + geom_text(hjust = 1.2) + 
    theme_classic() + theme(axis.title = element_blank(), axis.ticks = 
    element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), legend.position =
    "none")  + geom_errorbarh(height = .1)
#dev.off()
```

When I run the code, the pops with the same color listed in the input end up being the same color, but they do not become the color I want them to be. I have tried this with the colors in quotes as well as with the colors listed in hexadecimal, but I get the same problem either way. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You don't need all these `tbl$` in `aes()`. You already say `ggplot` to use `tbl`.

Comment: You can use `scale_colour_manual`. Reference: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_manual.html

Comment: The first pointer in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778302/plotting-point-estimates-with-error-bars-for-different-groups/34779537#comment57340243_34779537), [in your former questing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778302/plotting-point-estimates-with-error-bars-for-different-groups), already say what Pascal say above.

Comment: Maybe `tbl$color` is a factor?

Comment: you need to be very careful when you code Things. Look at the difference betwene these two statements `+ scale_colour_manual(values=tbl$color)` and `+ scale_colour_manual(values=color)` (the latter is the correct solution as the pointer pointed out above points out and as [Pascal points out in his first comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801653/how-do-i-get-ggplot-to-read-the-colors-i-am-feeding-it#comment57346621_34801653))

Comment: If you supply a minimal reproducible example to go along with your question it would be much easier for us to help you identify the problem.

Comment: Or look into `scale_color_identity()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to conditionally highlight points in ggplot2 facet plots - mapping color to column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804504/how-to-conditionally-highlight-points-in-ggplot2-facet-plots-mapping-color-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

I'm still new to R (and SO) but afaik `aes(colour=xxx)` doesn't set the actual colour, it determines the `scale_color_xxx` to apply. You seem to want the colour to change with each `Populations2`, so change the colour series based on that, if that makes sense.

Sorry, don't have enough rep (yet) to post an image of the output I get as well.

```
txt <- "Populations alpha   SE  Z   sample  color
Pop1    0.029000    0.003589    8.116   9   red
Pop2    0.031868    0.003498    8.231   9   red
Pop3    0.028969    0.003765    7.942   8   blue
Pop4    0.030651    0.003479    8.792   10  green"

tbl <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)

require(ggplot2)
tbl$Populations2 <- factor(tbl$Populations, as.character(tbl$Populations))

ggplot(tbl, aes(y = Populations2, 
                x = alpha, 
                xmin = alpha - SE, 
                xmax = alpha + SE, 
                label = Populations2,
                colour = Populations2
                )) + 
    geom_point(colour = "black") + 
  geom_text(hjust = 1.2) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "none") + 
  geom_errorbarh(height = .1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = as.character(tbl$color))
```

Comment: +1 This works. Some nitpicking, though: I know you copied some of the code from the original post, but you do not need to make a new factor variable, `Populations2`, since `ggplot` coerces character to factor automatically, you can just use `Populations`. Also, you can set `colour = color` in the `ggplot(aes(...))` function, then use `scale_color_identity()` instead of `scale_color_manual(...)`, as per @Heroka 's suggestion in the comments.

Comment: Also, there is an argument for using `library` and not `require` in your code unless you explicitly need `require` [(see this nice post)](http://yihui.name/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/)